# SASS add nested padding dynamically to inner childrens

Tags: html, css, sass

Hi I've my nested hierarchy gets generated dynamically

```
<p-tree>
  <li class="drop-point"></li>
  <li class="p-treenode">
    <div class="p-treenode-content">CONTENT 1</div>
     <ul class="p-treenode-children">
         <p-tree>
            <li class="drop-point"></li>
            <li class="p-treenode">
              <div class="p-treenode-content">NESTED CONTENT 1</div>
              <ul class="p-treenode-children">
               .......
             </ul>
            </li>
         </p-tree>
     </ul>
 </li>
</p-tree>
```

```
 p-tree ::ng-deep p-treenode .p-treenode-content + .p-treenode-children {
     .p-treenode-content {
        padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
    }
 }
```

The above code gives padding to the first level and keeps padding left 1 rem for all childrens.

I'm not sure how do we keep adding padding-left to each node so for example

First nested children padding-left 0px 0px 0px 1rem

Second nested children padding-left  0px 0px 0px 2rem (relative to root p-tree element) (it should keep adding 1rem)

Comment: You can apply the padding to `.p-treenode`